# Python: как записать в область видимости на уровень выше?

Tags: python

Есть такой упрощённый пример:

```py
def Bbb():
    aaa = False
    def Ccc():
        aaa = aaa or True
    Ccc()
    print(aaa)
Bbb()
```

Я хочу, чтобы `print()` выдавал `True`. Как это грамотно сделать по-питонически?

Comment: по-питонически функция должна возвращать значение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `nonlocal`

```
def Bbb():
    aaa = False
    def Ccc():
        nonlocal aaa
        aaa = aaa or True
    Ccc()
    print(aaa)
Bbb()
```

Вывод в терминале

```
True
```

Ключевое слово `nonlocal` используется для указания, что вы хотите изменить значение переменной, находящейся в внешней функции, а не создать новую локальную переменную с тем же именем.

---

p.s. а *по-питонически* вот так можно

```
def Bbb():
    aaa = False
    def Ccc(aa):
        aa = aa or True
        return aa
    aaa = Ccc(aaa)  # Вызываем функцию Ccc() для изменения значения aaa
    print(aaa)
Bbb()
```

Comment: это не по-питонически

Comment: а *по-питонически²*  ответ у @CameL

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы не передать `aaa` в качестве параметра в функцию `Ссс`, и потом из нее его вернуть

```
def Bbb():
    aaa = False
    def Ccc(aaa):
        aaa = aaa or True
        return aaa
    return Ccc(aaa)
print(Bbb())
```